# How to load a ByteArray FLV in OSMF?

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, arrays, flv, osmf

I'm working on a local application ( it's not a website or nothing related ) and I have various FLVs with a very simple *encryptation* method by now (just like adding 10 at each byte).

I can load/play them using NetStream.appendBytes() after decrypting, but that happens only after I read all video data it's **not** streamed.

What I really need is to **stream** those videos from a remote url, and decrypting while receiving data, using a OSMF based player that I already have built.
I'm lost on how OSMF deals with FLV, otherwise, I would try to create a plugin or something like.
I'd be very thankful if someone point me how to deal with that.

But I'd be happy if someone help me to find a way to load a local file using OSMF, passing a ByteArray value, instead of a url (below). Or even giving me directions to create a OSMF plugin to solve my problem.

```
videoElement.resource = "video_url/video.flv";
```

This is my current code just to play my decoded FLV byte array

```
private function playBytes(bytes:ByteArray):void 
{
            // detecting it's header
            if (bytes.readUTFBytes(3) != "FLV")
            {
                _text.appendText("\nFile \""+ file +"\" is not a FLV")
                return void;
            }

            bytes.position = 0;
            netConnection.connect(null);
            netStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
            netStream.client = { onMetaData:function(obj:Object):void { } }
            video.attachNetStream(netStream);

            addChild(video); 


            // put the NetStream class into Data Generation mode
            netStream.play(null);
            // before appending new bytes, reset the position to the beginning
            netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
            // append the FLV video bytes
            netStream.appendBytes(bytes);
}
```

Comment: What are you asking?  How to stream video with `appendBytes`, or how to use `appendBytes` with OSMF?

Comment: The second option. As you can see, I can already play a video using only appendBytes and I cannot "afford" to create another video player from scratch. I need to stream that videos, but if turns to be a really hard task, I could work with it **locally**.

Comment: What happens when you remove your encryption and just try plain? Does it stream?

Comment: Using netStream.appendBytes, yes! But not using OSMF.

Comment: I see this is from a while back... did you solve it? :)

Comment: @davidkomer Nope. I gave up trying, but seems a friend did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting post, I'd be interested to see the answer. Looking at something similar myself, though not with a stream, I came across the following.

http://ntt.cc/2008/07/15/bitsreader-read-bits-from-given-bytearray.html

After passing the byte array you can use bits.read(8) of a 10 bit array. Perhaps this would send you down the correct path? Otherwise, I'm thinking you'd need to break it apart and essentially do smaller sections to buffer in order to concatenate all the buffered data...

Just a thought,

Comment: I can already read a FLV using it's byteArray with that code i've shown, the link you posted seems to be a old way of doing what I did.
The appendBytes is a "recent" feature, that I discovered [here](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1689).